# Binance API futures adjust leverage

Tags: python-3.x, binance-api-client

How can i adjust the leverage of an order using the following command

```
client.futures_create_order(symbol="VETUSDT", side"BUY", type="MARKET", quantity="100")
```

something like:

```
client.futures_create_order(symbol="VETUSDT", side"BUY", type="MARKET", quantity="100", leverage=5)
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before you place the Trade, you first want to adjust the leverage

```
client.futures_change_leverage(symbol='VETUSDT', leverage=50)
```

This should be how it is done however I have had issues where this adjustment does not go through